# python 3.x input in a different script

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

I found some problem trying to create a py script that call another py script and input some int to it. I explain better:

my first script is simpleScript.py

```
def addition ( a , b ) :
    c = a + b 
    return c
x = int ( input ( 'input a int' ) )
y = int ( input ( 'input a int' ) )
summ = addition ( x , y )
```

on my second script tester.py I suppose to do something like this:

```
call simpleScript.py ;
input 4 as x ;
input 8 as y ;
run simpleScript.py using those two input ;
```

and some more stuff. The problem is that I can't really find ho to input it properly. Once I get it I'll be able to do all of the rest.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what about passing parameters instead?

Comment: Is there a reason you are using `input` if you do not actually want the user to input values? Just wanting to clarify, is the second script for test purposes, and you are wanting to simulate the inputs as a unit test of the first script? If so, this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46222661/how-to-mock-a-user-input-in-python - you want to look at mocking `builtins.input` to have a fake return value (the number a human would have entered).

Comment: @Bilkokuya yep, I'm coding a script in order to test my first script simulatin all the possible input that a human can input.

Comment: Excellent, the solution I've linked should help you a long way. I'm going to flag this as duplicate - don't think of that as a bad thing though, it'll hopefully give you the answer from the previous time this was asked :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mock standard input - multi line in python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39908390/mock-standard-input-multi-line-in-python-3)

Comment: I actually checked them already but I could not figure it out. So I ask it again with a simple example order to understand it properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering to help OP as there is a slightly difference between this and the linked duplicate (although I'd still suggest this is a duplicate that should be closed). The input here is being run at the module scope - so will execute when first loaded. i.e. `simpleScript.py` will ask for input when it is first called by `import`.

To do this in a test scenario, I'd firstly recommend to change this so that simpleScript.py provides a function that can be run. That way - the same solutions as the duplicates provide can be used.

But for this specific case where `simpleScript.py` does directly execute code, we can test the functionality with a test script below:

```
from unittest.mock import patch
from io import StringIO

@patch("sys.stdin", StringIO("1\n4"))
def test_simpleScript():
    import simpleScript

test_simpleScript()
```

This works by mocking the `stdin` (commandline input) to return 1, a new line then 4. Because of how `input` works with `stdin` this will return 1 on the first call to `input` and then `4` on the next call.

When we `import` the `simpleScript` module - all the code in it is executed. Because of the above mock patch we did, any calls to `input` during this will read the numbers we have given it. As the module only executes the first time it is loaded - you may have issues if you try multiple tests one after another. See here for how to force a module to reload if that is the case: [How do I unload (reload) a Python module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437589/how-do-i-unload-reload-a-python-module)